# boot updated kernel image on beagleboard

Tags: command-line, linux-kernel

Boot updated kernel image on beagleboard.

I had installed a kernel on Beagle-board to update image of kernel to it. I've used this command:

```
 $ sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.2.0.49-omap
```

It installed the kernel on Beagle-board and it also generated an `initrd` image for this version but it didn't generate a `uImage` and `zImage`. Actually I want to boot this kernel on Beagle-board, can anybody give me some steps on how to boot a new kernel which is recently installed on Beagle-board but doesn't get booted on power on.

If it doesn't generate any kind of `uImage` how can I make it bootable?

Related information: Board → Beagle-board XM port OS → Linux Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS